# Row spanning not working properly when you scroll

Tags: ag-grid

I made some modifications in the given example in the website:

[ag-Grid row spanning example](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/xXsvEosb2FfzXl5eDWz3?p=preview&preview)

specifically, I added the following:

```
} else if (athlete === "Jenny Thompson") {
        return 500;
...

cellClassRules: { "cell-span": "value==='Jenny Thompson' || value==='Aleksey Nemov' || value==='Ryan Lochte'" },
```

At first look, it seems that 'Jenny Thompson' spans properly.  However, when you scroll a little bit further, the spanning stops.   But if you click on 'Jenny Thompson' and scroll, the spanning continues up to the 500th cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that when you scroll down, the previous rows are removed and replaced by new ones.  Thus, the rowSpan is removed.  I did a workaround for this.

In rowData, I added these new properties:  `rowSpan-<index>` and `grpSpan-<index>`.  `rowSpan-<index>` will indicate how many rows a cell span to.  I have to calculate the rowspan for the other rows under the main group cell.  For example, my cell spans 50 rows.  Therefore, it has a rowspan of 50.  The cell below it will have a rowspan of 49, the next cell will have 48, and so on.  This is so when the rows above got removed from viewport, the new cells still know how many rows it need to span.  These other cells that have a rowspan less than the main (50 in this example), will have another property `grpSpan-<index>`.  This is just to identify that they are part of the main group.  By the way, `index` is the column index.

Then I added the following property to `columnDefs`:

```
    column['rowSpan'] = (params) => {
      return params.data[`rowSpan-<index>`] ? params.data[`rowSpan-<index>`] : 1;
    };
    column['cellClassRules'] = {
      'cell-span': (params) => {
        return params.data[`rowSpan-<index>`] ? true : false;
      },
      'cell-group': 'true',
      'cont-span': (params) => {
        return params.data[`grpSpan-<index>`] ? true : false;
      }
    };
```

In css:

```
.cell-span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d9dcde !important;
}

.cell-group {
  background: white;
}

.cont-span {
  color: white;
}
```

I hope this helps others struggling with this issue.